# disable mousewheel plugin over div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I'm using the mousewheel plugin that's shown here:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

And it works well for getting the page to scroll horizontally, but I want to temporarily disable that and revert to vertical scrolling when a couple specific divs pop up. I tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('html, div.everthing').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 1);
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    jQuery(".interests.content .child").mouseover(
      function stopHorizScroll(){
      var vScroll = [
        jQuery(".child.books").attr("class"),
        jQuery(".child.quotes").attr("class"),
        jQuery(".child.humans").attr("class"),
        jQuery(".child.travel").attr("class")
        ];

      var x = "show"

    if (vScroll[0].indexOf(x) !== -1) {
      jQuery('html, div.everthing').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
      return false; 
    }); 
    }
   });

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already bound the mousewheel event. `return false` does nothing to the event you previously bound. To do what you're trying to do, you'd need to unbind the original event, then rebind on mouseleave, or stop the propagation. I'm not sure if you can unbind/destroy the mousewheel event, and I'm not sure if `e.stopPropagation()` would work either.

Perhaps an easier solution would be to set a flag when someone hovers over that div, and prevent the horizontal scroll if the flag is set. For example, something like this might work:

```
var stopScroll = false;

jQuery('html, div.everthing').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
  if ( stopScroll ) return;

  this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 1);
  e.preventDefault();
});

jQuery(".interests.content .child").hover(function() {
  stopScroll = true;
}, function() {
  stopScroll = false;
});
```

Comment: Aagh good idea but it didn't work. It definitely changes the value of stopScroll on hover, but it doesn't do anything to disable the mousewheel plugin.

Comment: @user47143 You might need to double check everything in your code and ensure that stopScroll isn't turning off prematurely. I just tested this on jsFiddle, and can confirm that it's definitely possible: https://jsfiddle.net/3uLy7qnf/

Comment: Turned out some CSS z-indexing was interfering your code--it works beautifully